# c# coding error,showing expected '}'

Tags: c#

I am facing a very basic problem in C# programming that of a misplaced or missing '}'.I have checked everything but still it shows the same error.I am attaching the code.Please help me out to correct it.Since its very important for me.Thank You

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;

namespace pdf
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {//THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE THE ERROR IS SHOWING 
    private Font _largeFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18, Font.BOLD,       BaseColor.BLACK); 
    private Font _standardFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK); 
    private Font _smallFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    public void Build() 
    { 
        iTextSharp.text.Document doc = null;
        try 
        { 
            // Initialize the PDF document 
            doc = new Document(); 
             iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer =   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, 
             new System.IO.FileStream(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\ScienceReport.pdf", 
                System.IO.FileMode.Create));
   // Set margins and page size for the document 
   doc.SetMargins(50, 50, 50, 50); 
   // There are a huge number of possible page sizes, including such sizes as 
   // EXECUTIVE, LEGAL, LETTER_LANDSCAPE, and NOTE 
   doc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Width, 
       iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Height));
   // Add metadata to the document.  This information is visible when viewing the 
   // document properities within Adobe Reader. 
   doc.AddTitle("My Science Report"); 
   doc.AddCreator("M. Lichtenberg"); 
   doc.AddKeywords("paper airplanes");

   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageLabels pdfPageLabels = new    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageLabels(); 
   pdfPageLabels.AddPageLabel(1, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageLabels.EMPTY, "Basic     Formatting"); 
   pdfPageLabels.AddPageLabel(2, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageLabels.EMPTY, "Internal    Links"); 
   pdfPageLabels.AddPageLabel(3, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageLabels.EMPTY, "Bullet List"); 
   pdfPageLabels.AddPageLabel(4, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageLabels.EMPTY, "External Links"); 
   pdfPageLabels.AddPageLabel(5, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageLabels.EMPTY, "Image"); 
   writer.PageLabels = pdfPageLabels; 
   } 
       catch (iTextSharp.text.DocumentException dex) 
       { 
       // Handle iTextSharp errors 
       } 
       finally 
       { 
         // Clean up 
           doc.Close(); 
           doc = null; 
       } 

     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: How can you tell everything is correct with indentation like this?

Comment: Format your code in a readable way. It may make your life easier.

Comment: A tip to diagnosing these issues is to save a copy of your file, then slowly delete methods and code till error goes away (in the copy)

Comment: I am sorry to have posted a question in such an amateurish manner.Since it's been regarded as 'off-topic' pertaining to the length of the code,you can close it as my query has been answered.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields should be defined outside the Main method, It should be like this:

```
namespace pdf
{
    class Program
    {
        private Font _largeFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18, Font.BOLD,       BaseColor.BLACK); 
        private Font _standardFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK); 
        private Font _smallFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ......
        }
        ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't define fields, properties or methods inside of you `Main()`-method
Maybe try to rearrange your code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.Build();
}

private Font...
public void Build() 
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanx a tonne,you solved my problem.i am really sorry if my question seemed a bit stupid and since am posting a question for the first time here it may not have been framed well.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is pointing you to the exact position.

Please replace `//THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE THE ERROR IS SHOWING` with }.

At least this should fix the error you pointed out.